# Node.js, express, and using development versus production in app.configure

Tags: node.js, express, development-environment, production-environment

What is the easiest method to let express know what environment I am in?  E.g. I want do do the below to make a connection to redis depending on what env I am in.  Can this be done from the command line?

```
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
  var r = require("redis").createClient(6379,'127.0.0.1');
});
app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  r = redis.createClient(6379,'46.137.195.230', { detect_buffers: true });
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your approach is ok, but you can make something more generic, like storing the config data for Redis in a file or passing the host and port like arguments:

`node app.js REDIS_HOST REDIS_PORT`

Then in your app you can grab them using process.argv:

```
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
  var r = require("redis").createClient(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
});
app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  var r = require("redis").createClient(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], { detect_buffers: true });
});
```

Update:

Express will know in what environment you're in by looking at the NODE_ENV variable (process.env.NODE_ENV): https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L55

You can set that variable when starting the app like so: `NODE_ENV=production node app.js` (recommended), setting process.env.NODE_ENV manually in your node app before the Express code or putting that env var in ~/.profile like Ricardo said.

Comment: You could go further by defining the defaults for those parameters in your package.json file or another configuration file.

Answer (score 26):

To expand on the idea of using a config.json file:

```
// config.json
{
  "development": {
    "redisPort": 6379,
    "redisHost": "127.0.0.1",
    "errorHandlerOptions": {"dumpExceptions": true, "showStack": true}
  },
  "production": {
    "redisPort": 6379,
    "redisHost": "46.137.195.230",
    "errorHandlerOptions": {"dumpExceptions": false, "showStack": false}
  }
}
```

Load the config file and switch based on env.

```
// app.js
var config = require('./config.json')[app.get('env')];
app.use(express.errorHandler(config.errorHandlerOptions));
var r = require("redis").createClient(config.redisPort,config.redisHost);
```

Make sure the NODE_ENV is set on each server (see other answers, one way: `NODE_ENV=production node app.js`), and this way the config variable has the settings appropriate to the server it runs on.

Answer (score 19):

Just set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `production` or `development`, as seen in express' docs: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration

I just leave `NODE_ENV=development` in the dev machine's `~/.profile` (.bashrc or bash_profile on linux), and do the same for `production` ones.

Comment: Just a heads up. The link you posted is now broken. I belive the eqivelant is http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set

Comment: Or possibly: http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#set-node_env-to-production

Answer (score 9):

I did somthing even more comprehensive by ordering the sources of such parameters :

```
    var env = process.argv[2] || process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
    var mongourl = process.argv[3] || process.env.NODE_DB || 'mongodb://localhost/default'
    var port = process.env.PORT || 9001
```

This way you can use command line args, env settings and default values.

Comment: With your technique above, unless you manually do `process.env.NODE_ENV = process.argv[2]` when passing an env param on the command line, Express will still think your in process.env.NODE_ENV mode (dev by default).

Comment: True. I may have to change that. Thank you for your observation.

Comment: Replacing `var env =` with `var env = process.env.NODE_ENV =` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use config module that allows to create multiple config files 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

Eg default.json , production.json

And start your server wIth

export set  NODE_ENV=production && npm start